# GCP「App Engine default service account」の復元方法を教えてください

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud

GCPで「App Engine default service account」（appspot.gserviceaccount.comドメインのアカウント）を「IAMと管理 > サービスアカウント」と「IAMと管理 > IAM」から誤って削除してしまいました。

GAE絡みのサービスが何も利用できなくなってしまったため、同サービスアカウントを復元したいのですが、うまく復元できておりません。
復元までのご助言をいただけないでしょうか？

以下に自分が試みた復元方法とその結果を示します。

## 1. 参考にしたサイト

以下のサイト等を参考に、2パターンの復元方法を試みました

### 【REST API の repair API を用いた復元方法】

Google Cloud のデフォルトサービスアカウントの復元？
  https://qiita.com/v-o-v/items/cc036061d153aa1210cc

Google App Engine Deploy Error Code 9
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44676231/google-app-engine-deploy-error-code-9
  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/v1/apps/repair

### 【gcloud コマンドを利用した復元方法】

削除されたデフォルトのサービス アカウントの復元
  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/access-control?hl=JA#repair-service-account
  https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/app/repair?hl=JA

## 2. 実行結果

【REST API の repair API を用いた復元方法】
  ［実行したコマンド］

```
gcloud auth application-default login
gcloud auth application-default print-access-token
curl -X POST  -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer ya2...YkZ" https://appengine.googleapis.com/v1/apps/{project-id}:repair
```

［curlのレスポンス］

```
HTTP/2 200
{
  "name": "apps/{project-id}/operations/34b...845",
  "metadata": {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.appengine.v1.OperationMetadataV1",
    "method": "google.appengine.v1.Applications.RepairApplication",
    "insertTime": "2019-01-08T01:19:48.709Z",
    "user": "{email}",
    "target": "apps/{project-id}"
  }
}
```

［実行結果］

```
「IAMと管理 > サービスアカウント」と「IAMと管理 > IAM」上では、「App Engine default service account」の作成を確認できず
```

【gcloud コマンドを利用した復元方法】
  ［実行したコマンド］

```
gcloud config set project {project-id}
gcloud beta app repair
```

［最後のコマンドの実行結果］

```
Waiting for operation [apps/{project-id}/operations/047...3ad] to complete...failed.
Repairing the app [{project-id}]...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.app.repair) Error Response: [13] An internal error occurred while ensuring the default service account exists.
```

［実行結果］

```
「IAMと管理 > サービスアカウント」と「IAMと管理 > IAM」上では、「App Engine default service account」の作成を確認できず
```

Answer (score 1):

ちょうど同じ状態になっていたので回答しておきます。

以下のissueにあるように、1/8時点でknown issueとして対応中とのことでしたが、現在1/30時点で進捗がなさそうなので、現状は新たにprojectを作成しなおすしかないと思います。

> This is a known issue, and Engineering is already working towards a fix. No estimated time to resolution has been set. Meanwhile, you may follow developments in this thread.

see: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/122163562

F.Y.I. ちなみにgcpugのslackで質問したら親切な人達が秒で教えてくれました。